# Store procedure de Select en Oracle no encuentra datos

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

Tengo el siguiente código en Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STOREDSUBMODULOS(IDCATMODULO IN NUMBER , IDCATSUBMODULO OUT NUMBER , CLAVESUBMODULO OUT VARCHAR2 , DESCRIP OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    ID_CAT_SUBMODULO    ,
    CLAVE_SUBMODULO     ,
    DESCRIPCION         
    INTO 
    IDCATSUBMODULO      ,
    CLAVESUBMODULO      ,
    DESCRIP
  FROM 
    SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO
  WHERE
    ID_CAT_MODULO = IDCATMODULO;
END STOREDSUBMODULOS;  
/
DECLARE
   IDCATMODULO NUMBER(5); 
   IDCATSUBMODULO NUMBER(5); 
   CLAVESUBMODULO VARCHAR2(10); 
   DESCRIP VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
  STOREDSUBMODULOS(IDCATMODULO, IDCATSUBMODULO, CLAVESUBMODULO, DESCRIP);
END;
```

y ya tengo la tabla SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO creada y llena, pero lo que quiero es que el procedure haga un vil select, a la hora de ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT 
    ID_CAT_SUBMODULO    ,
    CLAVE_SUBMODULO     ,
    DESCRIPCION         
  FROM 
    SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO;
```

hace lo que quiero que haga el procedure.
Alguna idea?

Comment: No encuentra datos de que tabla?, después comentas que "hace lo que quieres que haga", si funciona o no? se más especifico Omar! :)

Comment: La tabla de donde debe sacar los datos se llama SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO, está en el FROM, el programa corre, pero no muestra los registros, dice "no data found"

Comment: O sea, cuando se ejecuta la sentencia que puse hasta el final hace el "SELECT", que es lo que quiero que haga el procedure

Comment: AYUDA POR FAVOR!

Comment: Tu SP esta realizando un select a la tabla : SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO  si menciona el mensaje ""no data found" es que la tabla no contiene datos. Realiza la consulta SELECT * FROM SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO; y encontraras que tu tabla esta vacía, que es lo que deseas encontrar?

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, ni tenemos los medios de reproducir tu problema porque no sabemos cuales son tus datos, cuales son los valores que le pasas al stored procedure, etc... Se necesita un [mcve]. Además, aunque sí encontrara los datos, no veo que tu SP haga algo con los datos. ¿Que se supone que debe hacer?  Será que piensas que simplemente por ejecutar un `SELECT` dentro de un SP, que esto resultará en devolver los resultados, algo como hace SQL Server?  Los SP en Oracle no funcionan así.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que por cada valor en el 'Where' me debe devolver unas siete filas por que la tabla de la que quiero consultar información es una tabla hija, y si, lo que quiero es simplemente consultar los datos que tiene. Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Con este código me consulta perfectamente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STOREDSUBMODULOS(IDCATMODULO    IN NUMBER,
                                         IDCATSUBMODULO OUT NUMBER,
                                         CLAVESUBMODULO OUT VARCHAR2,
                                         DESCRIPT        OUT VARCHAR2,
                                         PV_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2) IS

ID_CAT_SUBMODULO NUMBER(5):=null;
CLAVE_SUBMODULO VARCHAR2(10):=null;
DESCRIP VARCHAR2(100):=null;
BEGIN
SELECT ID_CAT_SUBMODULO, CLAVE_SUBMODULO, DESCRIPCION
INTO ID_CAT_SUBMODULO, CLAVE_SUBMODULO, DESCRIP
FROM SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULO
WHERE ID_CAT_MODULO = IDCATMODULO;

IDCATSUBMODULO:=ID_CAT_SUBMODULO;
CLAVESUBMODULO:=CLAVE_SUBMODULO;
DESCRIPT:=DESCRIP;

exception
 when no_data_found then
   PV_ERROR:='No Se encuentra el DATO en la Base';
END STOREDSUBMODULOS;
```

Comment: yA LO UTILICÉ Y AGREGUE LA PARTE DONDE SE EJECUTA, EFECTICAMENTE YA NO MANDA ESE ERROR, PERO MANDA ESTO:
Informe de error -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYS.STOREDSUBMODULOS", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 8
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: Es que la tabla SIOV_CAT_SUBMODULOS es una tabla hija, por cada valor del campo ID_CAT_MODULOS(que pertenece a la tabla madre) corresponden siete filas que son las que quiero consultar con este procedure

Comment: Pasame los scripts de estructuras y datos de tus tablas.